# How to extract text between a phrase and a semicolon using regex

Tags: regex

I have a multiple text rows in a text file which I need to extract out particular values. I have just started learning RegEx and was trying my hand at using it for this situation. The values that are to be extracted are digits but can be either integer or decimal with varying decimal places.

Two examples of the text rows are shown below.

```
settings parameterName1 = 15.0;
settings parameterName2 = 75.0; # Increase 25% from 50.0;
```

The RegEx string below works for the first text row but not for the second text row.

```
(?<=\bsettings.*\=\s).*(?=\;)\b
```

The results that I get from the RegEx string are shown below - the second row did not output only the digit values I was looking for (i.e. I expected to see 15.0 for the first row and 75.0 for the second row only and not get the # comment text).

```
15.0;
75.0; # Increase 25% from 50.0;
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm surprised the lookbehind with a variable length works. What regex engine is this? All the ones I know have a problem with that construction.

Comment: Hey @Jongware, I tried this RegEx string in both Expresso and in C#.

Answer (score 2):

> The results that I get from the RegEx string are shown below

This is because `.*` is *greedy*. When it has an option to stop matching or to continue matching, it will try to match as many characters as possible.

An easy fix is to add a reluctant qualifier `?` to `.*` - i.e.

```
(?<=\bsettings.*\=\s).*?(?=\;)\b
```

A better fix would be to replace `.` with `[^;]`, which would also prevent backtracking:

```
(?<=\bsettings.*\=\s)[^;]*(?=\;)\b
```

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight, I didn't quite understand about the greedy behaviour of .* and backtracking until you explained it. Also the [ ^; ]* works too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using groups rather than lookahead/lookbehind -- the regexes will be simpler and more readable. You can you use the following regex, and select the second group:

```
(settings .*= )([^;]*;)
```

Comment: Hey @maxymoo, how do i select the second group? I tried adding a \2 at the end of the RegEx string but didn't get any text output. I am using C# in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a group match instead of the look-behind and look-ahead:

```
/settings.*?=\s*?([\d.]+)/g
```

then access the numbers through group(1) of each match.

Notice the use of the lazy quantifier '?'. You can read up on lazy quantifiers here - http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution.

Comment: James, thanks for pointing the link out - reading up on it now.